# HTML font-family setup

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup the font-family "Ravie" in a HTML document using the following code:

```
<h2><font font-family="ravie">Articles</font></h2>
```

but this is not working. Why not?

Answer (score 8):

To use the [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/conform.html#deprecated) [`FONT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2) tag:

```
<h2><font face="ravie">Articles</font></h2>
```

Better yet is to use [inline styles](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2):

```
<h2 style="font-family:ravie" >Articles</h2>
```

And even better is to use [header style information](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3):

```
<head>
    <style>
    h2 {font-family: ravie;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Articles</h2>
</body>
```

Best of all is to move the style declaration to an [external style sheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.3), and this is standard practice unless you have a strong reason for not doing so.

Comment: I did not downvote, and I see you indicated its deprecated status, but **why even suggest it?!?!?!?!** :P

Comment: Because the question specifically asked how to do this using the font tag. There are legitimate reasons for using the `FONT` tag, e.g., cross-platform email HTML support.

Comment: fair enough, I was just playing :)

Answer (score 3):

you do it like this:

`<h2 style="font-family:arial">...</h2>`

or you do it in your stylesheet. like this:

```
<h2 class="somthing">...</h2>
.something { font-family:arial }
```

don't use `<font>` tags as they have been deprecated.

read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_family_%28HTML%29

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 style="font-family:tahoma">Articles</h2>
```

The `<font>` tag is deprecated in the latest versions of HTML (HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0).

Comment: You can just indent your code with four spaces instead of encoding it with entities (I'd done that for you earlier)...

Answer (score 0):

The `<font>` tag is deprecated and no longer used. The better practice now is to use CSS combined with selectors, divs, and spans to style fonts.

Answer (score 0):

```
#obj{
font-family:verdana;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2><td align="center" class="addfont">Articles</h2>

.addfont
{
    font-family: 'ravie';
}
```

can you try like this?
It's very simple .
Another advantage is the script can be used inside the page or outside the page,but if you use the outside of page.
You must use below the line

```
<link href="/styles/Filename.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```